# JSON response with a single request

Tags: node.js, express

### I am trying `async.parallel` feature to get JSON response from two different tables in a single URL

- I am having problem debugging the error

***Scenario is like this***

- There is a database
- there are two tables in that database
- I am converting JSON response from both the tables with a single
  request async

Any Ideas

**My express program ::**

```
var express = require('express')
  , async = require('async')
  , http = require('http')
  , mysql = require('mysql'); 

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'xxxx',
    password: "xxxx",
    database: 'test123'
});

connection.connect(); 

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8084);


app.get('/',function(request,response){
    var first, second;

    async.series( [

        // Get the first table contents
        function ( callback ) {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM test1', function(err, rows, fields)

                {
                        console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                        first = JSON.stringify(rows);
                        callback();
                });
        },

        // Get the second table contents
        function ( callback ) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM test2', function(err, rows, fields)

            {
                    console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                    second = JSON.stringify(rows);
                    callback();
            });
        }

    // Send the response
    ], function ( error, results ) {
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        response.end({
            'first' : first,
            'second' : second
        });
    } );

} );

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**error::**

```
Express server listening on port 8084
Connection result error null
Connection  result error null

TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (http.js:783:11)
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (http.js:964:16)
    at /home/ubuntu/rainmelon/sample_programs/express_folder_json/app.js:55:18
    at /home/ubuntu/rainmelon/sample_programs/express_folder_json/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:229:13
    at /home/ubuntu/rainmelon/sample_programs/express_folder_json/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:139:25
    at /home/ubuntu/rainmelon/sample_programs/express_folder_json/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:226:17
    at /home/ubuntu/rainmelon/sample_programs/express_folder_json/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:553:34
    at Query._callback (/home/ubuntu/rainmelon/sample_programs/express_folder_json/app.js:48:21)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/home/ubuntu/rainmelon/sample_programs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:66:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/home/ubuntu/rainmelon/sample_programs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:143:8)
```

### AFTER EDITING

**express program::**

```
var express = require('express')
  , async = require('async')
  , http = require('http')
  , mysql = require('mysql'); 

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'xxx',
    password: "xxx",
    database: 'test123'
});

connection.connect(); 

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8084);


app.get('/',function(request,response){
    var first, second;

    async.series( [

        // Get the first table contents
        function ( callback ) {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM test1', function(err, rows, fields)

                {
                        console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                        first = JSON.stringify(rows);
                        callback();
                });
        },

        // Get the second table contents
        function ( callback ) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM test2', function(err, rows, fields)

            {
                    console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                    second = JSON.stringify(rows);
                    callback();
            });
        }

   // Send the response
], function ( error, results ) {
    response.json({
        'first' : first,
        'second' : second
    });
} );

} );

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error isn't with `async.parallel()`. The stack trace mentions:

```
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (http.js:783:11)
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (http.js:964:16)
at /home/ubuntu/rainmelon/sample_programs/express_folder_json/app.js:55:18
```

And line `55` of `app.js` is presumably:

```
response.end({
```

---

The issue is that the built-in [`response.end()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding) doesn't support auto-serializing an `Object` to JSON. It only accepts a `String` or a `Buffer` for `data`.

You'll either need to `stringify` the `Object` yourself.

```
response.end(JSON.stringify({
    // ...
}));
```

Or, you can use Express' [`.send()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send) or [`.json()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.json).

```
// Send the response
], function ( error, results ) {
    response.send({
        'first' : first,
        'second' : second
    });
} );
```

Either of the latter will also set the `Content-Type` for you.

Comment: @ [Jonathan Lonowski](http://stackoverflow.com/users/15031/jonathan-lonowski) ...... thanks your solution helped .... but please look at my updated question ...... i am trying to get my final solution like the one i have mentioned ..... **any ideas**

Comment: @Sky You're doubling up on the JSON encoding. `response.json()` will already `stringify` them along with the holding `Object`. So, you can just set `first = rows;` and `second = rows;` in each `connection.query()` callback.

Comment: Thanks .... again .... you mentioned as " latter will also set the Content-Type for you." .... does it mean i don't need to set my content type explicitly ?

Comment: @Sky Correct. You still can, but [Express will set it if you don't](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L190-L191).

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you take close look to the example from async.js documentation, you will notice that the scope of your "first" and "second" var where you save each result is wrong. You should call each callback with their respective error and response, and then use the array as in the example to build the final object to submit. (Or you can use a globar var, but that it is not a good idea). Cheers.

```
async.series([
    function(callback){
        // do some stuff ...
        callback(null, 'one');
    },
    function(callback){
        // do some more stuff ...
        callback(null, 'two');
    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results){
    // results is now equal to ['one', 'two']
});
```